# Unable to get id from the URL using params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to Express JS  and MongoDB so please go easy on me.
I'm following a tutorial of web development by colt steele. here is my code

```
app.get("/:id",async(req,res)=>
{
    const id= req.params['id'];
     console.log(id);
    const students= await Student.findById(id);
    console.log(students);
    res.render("studentdata/show",{students});
})
```

I'm trying to get the id using `req.params` but it is returning `favicon.ico`  .
This is the error I got
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvrpE.png)

I tried using `params['name']` (name field refers to student name in DB) which worked without any error. I  also tried using `_id` which gave me another error. I'm expecting params['id'] to return the id of the entry.

Comment: You are handling all requests to `/:id`. `/favicon.ico` matches `/:id`. You probably wanted to name your endpoint like `/students/:id`. `favicon.ico` is an icon you see in the tab bar

Comment: Thank you . I changed the route to /studentdata/:id .It's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Assuming that you are developing your application in localhost.
Its always a best practice to keep your backend stuffs seperate.
Instead of giving the route path as **app.get('/:id')** you could have used

```
app.get('/api/:id',async(req,res) =>{
    const id= req.params['id'];
     console.log(id);
    const students= await Student.findById(id);
    console.log(students);
    res.render("studentdata/show",{students});
})
```

And the url for this should be like this :

> http://localhost:port_number/api/student_id
> Here port number should be replaced with the port number on which your server is running . For example - 5000
> And student_id should be replaced with student id
> For example - 12345
> And the url shoud be like following:
> http://localhost:5000/api/12345

Comment: Thank you. I changed the route and it's working.